# issue when import ConditionalGeneration from transformers in python

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-3.7, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to import ConditionalGeneration from transformers in jupyter notebook

```
from transformers import ConditionalGeneration
```

but encounter following error.I install different version and different method for installing pytorch and transformers but I can't solve it.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10284\1006457458.py in <module>
      1 ## Tokenizer import
      2 
----> 3 from transformers import T5Tokenizer, ConditionalGeneration

ImportError: cannot import name 'ConditionalGeneration' from 'transformers' (C:\Users\lenovo\anaconda3\envs\latr\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no class named ConditionalGeneration in transformers  simply)
you need to specify one of the classes for example  [BartForConditionalGeneration](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.23.1/en/model_doc/bart#transformers.BartForConditionalGeneration),  [LEDForConditionalGeneration](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.23.1/en/model_doc/led#transformers.LEDForConditionalGeneration),  [LongT5ForConditionalGeneration](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.23.1/en/model_doc/longt5#transformers.LongT5ForConditionalGeneration) or any another encoder decoder transformer from hugging face